# Проблема с аутентификацией в EXIM4 MD5

Tags: exim, exim4

Есть exim4  пользователи хранятся в mysql пароли в MD5

```
CREATE TABLE mailboxes (
  id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  domain_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
  local_part VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  description VARCHAR(250) NULL,
  active TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  modified TIMESTAMP NULL
);
```

Пароль задаю так

```
INSERT INTO mailboxes VALUES(NULL,1,'joe',MD5('password'),'My account for joe@mydomain.com',1,NOW(),NOW());
```

Соответственно что нужно прописать в 20_exim4-config_mysql-authenticator чтобы аунтефикация работала?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Соответственно что нужно прописать в 20_exim4-config_mysql-authenticator

вероятно, речь о файле в каталоге `/etc/exim4/conf.d/auth`?

примерно так (скопировано с рабочей системы с адаптацией под ваши имена полей):

```
mysql_plain:
  driver = plaintext
  public_name = PLAIN
  server_condition = ${lookup mysql{select id from mailboxes where local_part = '${quote_mysql:$auth2}' and password = md5('${quote_mysql:$auth3}')}{yes}{no}}
  server_prompts = :
  server_set_id = $auth2

mysql_login:
  driver = plaintext
  public_name = LOGIN
  server_condition = ${lookup mysql{select id from mailboxes where local_part = '${quote_mysql:$auth1}' and password = md5('${quote_mysql:$auth2}')}{yes}{no}}
  server_prompts = Username:: : Password::
  server_set_id = $auth1

mysql_cram_md5:
  driver = cram_md5
  public_name = CRAM-MD5
  server_secret = ${lookup mysql{select password from mailboxes where local_part =  '${quote_mysql:$auth1}'}{$value}fail}
  server_set_id = $auth2
```

правда, не уверен за ту часть, которая про `cram_md5`: там, откуда я копировал, пароль в базе записан открытым текстом. воспользуйтесь примерами из `/etc/exim4/conf.d/auth/30_exim4-config_examples` для адаптации.

впрочем, если судить по [этой, например, инструкции](http://alex.mamchenkov.net/2010/06/24/exim-dovecot-and-mysql/), то и без данной части (про `cram_md5`) должно работать.